# Google chat badge not working anymore?

Tags: gmail, google-gadget

I was using google talk chat badge (chatback - small iframe code that enables remote user to chat with you as anonymous) for some years but now it is not working anymore. The generated code is fine as it seems it opens a new window and all but after a second, it redirects to support.google.com page which of course is not of much use.

I rechecked the code, generated new code, didn't help. Again redirects to support.google.com. The code is generated from http://www.google.com/talk/service/badge/New

Anyone knows what's going on? Have they discontinued it or?

Also, a suggestion - is there any alternative web-presence button like that for other messengers which don't require client on other end. For Skype, Windows Live or some other messenger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a while I used MeeboMe in combination with MeeboMe notifier but then it died as well (company was purchased by Google and the product was killed) I found some good alternatives myself so I am sharing them. Ironically, they are recommended by MeeboMe after they discontinued their service. Both are free.

- Zoho Live Support - https://chat.zoho.com/
- Yahoo! Pingbox - http://messenger.yahoo.com/pingbox/ (requires Yahoo! account but otherwise is great)

Too bad large companies simply kill useful products. But as far as I am concerned, Yahoo! Pinbox is even better than both Google chat badge and MeeboMe (at least for my needs) and can be customized to great extent.

Answer (score 1):

According to KatherineG at Google the chat badge is no longer supported.  http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chat/_VpluJc6IfU

We are looking into using Crafty Syntax for a replacement.
http://www.craftysyntax.com/

Comment: I settled with Meebo for now. It also has very nicely customizable guest-chat. Unfortunately it doesn't have downloadable client but there are plugins for some other messengers like Pidgin (maybe Trillian too haven't checked that one).

Comment: After MeeboMe also died just a couple of months later I had to look for other alternatives. Look in my own answer for these.

Answer (score 1):

Yup, been a while now - it was great while it lasted. The personal workaround that I am using is to sign up for a live chat service and hook it up with Gtalk. I am currently using ClickDesk - http://www.clickdesk.com/

Visitors chat using the live chat interface and I use the Gtalk interface.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend ClickDesk - http://www.clickdesk.com too if you like to use Google Talk or Skype.

However, if you want to code - you can use xmpp protocol and hook it up with Pidgin notifications. Google Appengine also has notifications which I believe is what ClickDesk uses.